# Filtering find output to find only the real source files?

Tags: find, filter

I have a big directory tree with sources files (*.c), where some, (but not all), of which are actually generated via a preprocess which produces the *whatever*.c from a *whatever*.qc file.

Often, I find myself needing to do something on these files, but only the ultimate source files -- that is, if there is a *whatever*.qc, there is no point in looking at *whatever*.c (but if there is no *whatsit*.qc then I do need to look at *whatsit*.c).

Starting from something like this:

```
find data-utils -name '*.qc' -o -name '*.c' | xargs grep SMS_GEN
```

and lets assume a portion of the output of the find is:

```
data-utils/whatever.c
data-utils/whatsit.c
data-utils/whatever.qc
```

Is there some existing tool I can use to filter the output of the find so I don't pass the *whatever*.c's to xargs (or whatever follows the find).  That is, the filtered result from above should be:

```
data-utils/whatsit.c
data-utils/whatever.qc
```

Or am I going to need to write something from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

Finding the files with a `.c` filename suffix, but returning the pathname of corresponding `.qc` files if such files exists:

```
find server/data-utils -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ -f "${pathname%.c}.qc" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "${pathname%.c}.qc"
        else
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This finds the pathnames of all the regular files in or under the `server/data-utils` search path that has names ending in `.c`.  For batches of these pathnames, a short shell script is called.  The shell script tests each given pathname with the `.c` replaced by `.qc`, and if that modified pathname refers to an existing regular file (or to a symbolic link to one), it is printed.  Otherwise, the original pathname is printed.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

Just a variation of the above with the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) applied:

```
find server/data-utils -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        qc_pathname=${pathname%.c}.qc

        if [ -f "$qc_pathname" ]; then
            out=$qc_pathname
        else
            out=$pathname
        fi

        printf "%s\n" "$out"
    done' sh {} +
```

... or even just

```
find server/data-utils -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        qc_pathname=${pathname%.c}.qc
        [ -f "$qc_pathname" ] && pathname=$qc_pathname
        printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

Comment: This is a novel idea.  I assume the sh-script could go in a file instead of being typed out each time?

Comment: @JohnHascall You would likely want to put this in a script, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an awk script to do the job.  It's not particularly efficient, O(n^2), but it has the benefit of not reordering the (unfiltered) lines.

```
function supercedes ( a, b ) {
        suffixa=match(a, /\.[^/.]*$/);
        suffixb=match(b, /\.[^/.]*$/);
        if ((suffixa == 0) || (suffixa != suffixb)) return 0;
        if (substr(a,1,suffixa) != substr(b,1,suffixb)) return 0;
        return (substr(a,suffixa) == A) && (substr(b,suffixb) == B);
}
BEGIN { n = 0; }
{ item[n++] = $0; }
END {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                show = 1;
                for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                        if (j != i) {
                                if (supercedes(item[i], item[j])) {
                                        show = 0;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }
                if (show) print item[i];
        }
}
```

sample usage:

```
find server/data-utils -name '*.qc' -o -name '*.c' | \
    awk -f filter.awk -vA=.c -vB=.qc
```