# Delete files same name but different file extension

Tags: bash, filenames, rm

I have a mess in my photo libary. I have files like these:

```
image-1.jpg 
image-1.jpeg
image-2.jpg
```

Now I want to delete all photos with the extension .jpeg when there is a file with the same name but with the extension .jpg.

How can I do this?

Comment: This askubuntu thread lists some answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48524/search-for-duplicate-file-names-within-folder-hierarchy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for f in *.jpeg; do
  [ -e "${f%.*}.jpg" ] && echo rm -- "$f"
done
```

(remove `echo` if happy).

With `zsh` and one `rm` invocation:

```
echo rm -- *.jpeg(e'{[ -e $REPLY:r.jpg ]}')
```

(change `*` to `**/*` to do that recursively, add the `D` glob qualifier, if you also want to consider hidden files or files in hidden directories).

Comment: No need to remove the `echo` ... just examine the script output, and if happy, rerun the script and pipe to `sh`!

Comment: For others that didn't know, this loop makes use of `${parameter%word}` [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (and [`-e` test](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)).

Comment: @JimL., I would not recommend that as that `echo` won't output the right code in the sh language (unless none of the file names contain characters special in the sh language). You'd need zsh and `print -r rm -- ${(qq)f}` for that.

Answer (score 5):

An adaption of [an answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517586/filtering-find-output-to-find-only-the-real-source-files/517608#517608):

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        jpg_pathname=${pathname%.jpeg}.jpg
        if [ -f "$jpg_pathname" ]; then
            printf "Would remove %s\n" "$pathname"
            # rm "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This finds the pathnames of all files with a `.jpeg` filename suffix in or below the current directory. For as large batches as possible of these pathnames, a short in-line script is called.  The script loops over the current batch of pathnames and detects any file that has the same filename stem followed by `.jpg`.  If a `.jpeg` file has a corresponding `.jpg` file, the `.jpeg` file is removed (if the commented out `rm` is activated).

Shorter version (with safety comment removed and no text output):

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        [ -f "${pathname%.jpeg}.jpg" ] && rm "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

(You will notice that this turned out as a recursive variation of [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517776/116858))

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
readonly path="${1:-./}"

for file in "${path}"*.jpeg; do
  if [[ -f ${file%.jpeg}.jpg ]]; then
    rm -- "$file"
    printf '%s\n' "removed duplicate file ${file}"
  fi
done
```

The readonly variable at the top let's you pass the path to the directory as an arg to the script.  It defaults to the current dir if no arg is given.

It simply loops through all files ending with '.jpeg' in the dir specified by the var path.  Then it strips the extension and tests if the same file exists with a .jpg extension.  If the .jpg dup exists, then the .jpeg file is considered the dup, and it is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Current answers answer the specific case in the question body, but for the case of deleting *all* other files, I combined [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517776/106132) with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164026/106132) on excluding glob matches:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in *.jpeg; do
  [ -e "$f" ] && echo rm -- "${f%.*}".!(jpeg)
done
```