# Remove all files with particular name but different extensions at once

Tags: terminal, delete, macos

I have a directory where I have the following set of files:

```
cheatsheetold.aux
cheatsheetold.log
cheatsheetold.out
cheatsheetold.pdf
cheatsheetold.synctex.gz
cheatsheetold.tex
cheatsheetnew.aux
cheatsheetnew.log
cheatsheetnew.out
cheatsheetnew.pdf
cheatsheetnew.synctex.gz
cheatsheetnew.tex
```

What I want to do is to remove all the `cheetsheetold.`

```
cheatsheetold.aux
cheatsheetold.log
cheatsheetold.out
cheatsheetold.pdf
cheatsheetold.synctex.gz
cheatsheetold.tex
```

without touching the `cheatsheetnew`

```
cheatsheetnew.aux
cheatsheetnew.log
cheatsheetnew.out
cheatsheetnew.pdf
cheatsheetnew.synctex.gz
cheatsheetnew.tex
```

I already had a look at [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517773/delete-files-same-name-but-different-file-extension), but it didn't solve the problem as there is a complete set of extension for both file names

Comment: which shell? in bash it works to run `rm -- cheatsheetold.*`

Comment: Great! Many thanks @fraleone. that worked! I think I'm on bash. but I'm not shure. How can I know for next time?

Comment: `echo $BASH` should print out something when you are on bash as should `echo $SHELL` in both cases might most likely be `/bin/bash` which is the quasi standard path to the bash shell (for instance on fedora and ubuntu)

Comment: many thanks @fraleone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not stated in which shell (bash, fish, zsh, csh) you desire to use some sort of wildcard when removing files.

As `bash` is a prominent shell I state that it would be possible to simply use this command:

```
rm -- cheatsheetold.*
```

note that the wildcard `*` is used after the `--` as to avoid any unindented mishaps by bash shell extensions

the command line `env | grep 'SHELL'`  might show you the shell you use. I have also tested the command line in the more POSIX reduced `dash` shell.

I simply do not use any other shells (like csh and tsh or fish) so I cannot tell how globbing works there.

another way to get an idea which shell is running might be this
`ps -p $$` where the `$$` should be the PID of the current process (the shell) and ps the tool to list processes limited to the PID of the current shell.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShellGlobbing

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @fraleone. Can you just tell me additionally, how to know which shell I used for the next time I ask a question about terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Unix does not have file-name-extensions, nor does Microsoft's Windows (not after Windows ME. However file-explorer still has the concept). What you need to do is find all files starting with ... (in your case starting with `cheatsheetold.`.

You can do this with `cheatsheetold.*`. It will then pass the file list to `rm`. You can use it with any command. It is not an `rm` thing.

Practice with `echo cheatsheetold.*`

Comment: thanks for your answer @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: what is the difference between `rm -- cheatsheetold.*` and `rm cheatsheetold.*`?

Comment: That would be a new question: but it will tell you for free, just type `man rm`. It means end of options, and as on option in a lot of commands. Anything after it even if it starts with a `-` or `--` is not an option. It this case it will be a filename.

Comment: thanks for your comment @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: @ecjb There is a urban legend/ story where somebody had a file named `--rf` in his home directory. Wanting to delete all files, he issued a `rm *` instead of `rm -- *` which the shell then expanded to something like `rm file1 file2 [......] --rf` meaning that even more files and subdirectories have been removed by "acccident" and unintentedly. Therefore there is no harm to use `--` for additional safety line in case of `*`.

Comment: It is `-rf` (one hython).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wildcard, but you got to be very careful as it can delete other files that may match.

```
rm cheatsheetold.*
```

The command above will delete any file whose name starts with `cheatsheetold.` and is followed by anything, so any extension.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. @HeysusEscobar